# Open local file in electron and render in wavesurfer.js

Tags: javascript, readfile, fs, electron

I'm working on an app built with electron, it should work with wavesurfer.js to display a waveform representing the audio file. However, I'm having trouble opening the file using the `fs` module and pushing the file content to wavesurfer via a Blob. The file loads and everything seems to work but when decoding wavesurfer says `Error decoding audiobuffer`.

Two things I thought maybe could influence this:

- The `fs.readFile` function takes an encoding as second parameter
- The Blob constructor takes an options object as second parameter, whithin this you can define the mimetype via the `type` property

However, until now both approaches have failed to fix the problem.

I hope somebody has a solution. (Could also be the `fs.readFile` function is entirely the wrong way to go and there's a much better way; I'm just looking for a relatively performant way of opening a file, any help is appreciated) Cheers!

Here's the code …

(I'm leaving out all the electron boilerplate, you can get it easily by doing `git clone https://github.com/sindresorhus/electron-boilerplate/`) – Include a script tag to `main.js` in the `index.html`, add a div with the id `wave-area` somewhere in the html and add a script tag to the the [wavesurfer.js library](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/katspaugh/wavesurfer.js/master/dist/wavesurfer.min.js). Also you will need a local copy of the [demo wav-file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/katspaugh/wavesurfer.js/master/example/media/demo.wav).

Then in the `main.js` file …

```
var fs = require('fs');

var wavesurfer = Object.create(WaveSurfer);
wavesurfer.init({
  container: '#wave-area'
});

fs.readFile('/path/to/demo.wav', function(err, data) {
  if (data && !err) {
    console.log('has data and no error!');
  }
  var file = new window.Blob([data]);
  wavesurfer.loadBlob(file);
}

wavesurfer.on('loading', function(e) {
  console.log('loading', e);
});

wavesurfer.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I finally found the solution! The blob which is passed to wavesurfer through the `loadBlob` method needs to transformed into an [Uint8Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array)

The working code looks like this

```
fs.readFile('/path/to/demo.wav', function(err, buffer) {
  // …
  var blob = new window.Blob([new Uint8Array(buffer)]);
  wavesurfer.loadBlob(blob);
}
```

Comment: thanks for this! it also works for `window.createObjectURL`